# How to fix wrong sorting in bootstrap-vue table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm making use of `bootstrap-vue`. Within the `table` component, I want my users to be able to sort values.

I set all the options for that but for some reason, the sorting isn't going as I espected.

I've checked the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/) about sorting and set things up. My problem is, is that the following numbers (when sorted descending) are sorted like this:

```
856.780
832.912
827.873.000
```

Obviously, the last one is greater than the first two, but for some reason this doesn't work.

Now, the sorting does go right when I loose the punctuation, but that makes an ugly table for numbers.

Again, following the `docs` (see above) I'm making use of the `sort-compare-options` prop:

```
sortOptions: {
    ignorePunctuation: true,
    numeric: true
}
```

**EDIT**

My fields looke like this:

```
fields: [
    { key: 'name', sortable: true, tdClass: 'table-cell-align' },
    { key: 'revenue', sortable: true },
    { key: 'costs', sortable: true },
    { key: 'result', sortable: true },
    { key: 'margin', sortable: true },
    { key: 'fte', sortable: true },
    { key: 'personell_costs_/_revenue', sortable: true},
    { key: 'other_costs_/_revenue', sortable: true},
    { key: 'revenue_/_fte', sortable: true},
    { key: 'details', sortable: false }
]
```

```
[
    {
        "name": "Medical Tattoo Innovations",
        "revenue": "34.254",
        "costs": "38.010",
        "result": "-4.414",
        "fte": "0",
        "margin": "0",
        "personell_costs_\/_revenue": "0",
        "other_costs_\/_revenue": "1",
        "revenue_\/_fte": "171.270",
        "details": "0"
    }
]
```

But this doesn't do the trick for me.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you provide your `fields` and `items` fields?

Comment: Hi, see my edit

Comment: And `items` field?

Comment: `items` are being pulled from my `api`. I can show you the `JSON` output. Is that helpfull?

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful.

Comment: OK. I just added an example row.

Answer (score 3):

`827.873.000` is a string in your items data, not a Number (and since it has more than one decimal, the browser String.localCompare(...) method (used internally by b-table) does not see that as a valid number, so sorts it as a String.

You can either convert it to a number beforehand (but loose the extra decimal values), or set up a custom sort compare routine for those field columns.

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#sort-compare-routine

Your custom sort compare routine (which compares two rows), would need to deal with splitting the string into numerical parts and sort by those values.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your amazing work on `bootstrap-vue`. I will take a dive into the custom compare routine.

Comment: You can check out this similar issue (with example solution) at https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/3755#issuecomment-515113082